# Is there a bash equivalent to zsh's file-type globbing?

Tags: bash, glob

In zsh you can qualify globs with file type assertions e.g. `*(/)` matches only directories, `*(.)` only normal files, is there a way to do the same thing in bash without resorting to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
ls -ltrd */ #match directories using -d and the slash "/"
```

or

```
echo */
```

or

```
for dir in */
do
  ...
done
```

If you need to do it recursive, and you have Bash 4+

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for dir in **/*/; do echo $dir; done
```

Comment: that is so obvious, i feel a little stupid... tho all the options to ls other than the -d are superfluous :)

Comment: dont feel bad, i feel the same way... cant believe i missed that one!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a way to do this directly, but don't forget that you can use the [test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) options `-d` and `-f` to determine whether name refers to a directory or a file.

```
for a in *; do
  if [ -d "$a" ]; then
    echo Directory: $a
  elif [ -f "$a" ]; then
    echo File: $a
  fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's worse than using find - I can use find with xargs to get a command line to pass to another script instead of testing each result separately. I just wanted a globbing based way because you can't use xargs with bash functions...

Comment: I'm surprised that you think that invoking several new processes is in some way better this direct approach. Could you explain more about what you want to do in the question?

Comment: to clarify, using ghostdog74's solution, i want to call a bash function `fooBar */` if i were to make `fooBar` a script i could `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 fooBar` which is much easier than constructing an array inside a for loop